Nextjs - Clerk web hook to sync supabase
The normal work flow :
When user hits a route that protected by Clerk, it triggers the app/api/clerk/webhook.
Inside the web hook I check specifically 2 event types. user create and delete.
If it is user-created event, I get the userid & email from Clerk, create a user with data from clerk in supabase database.
Everything works, I can see the user in Clerk and supabase created.
My NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/chat. So, after webhook runs, Clerk redirect to /chat.
Which is my server component app/chat/page.js
In this server component, I fetch user data from database and render a client-side component with some data.
This works most of the time. So, everything works in webhooks, user is created at clerk and supabase, I hit the /chat, get user data from database and render. However, sometimes I get the error rendered, because chat component runs before webhook completes. Everything still works behind the scenes I just don't have updated data. If I re-load the page, I get all the data rendered on the page. So I get the user data from database before its created actually. Any know why is this happening and how to solve it the best way?
If I change
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/chat to for example NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/another
and move chat, yes, it solves my problem, but I want to redirect to exactly that page and want to understand this does not work. First time working with webhooks.
